# Infowindow: link to zoom and center to marker onclick

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I have an array item and all I want to do is add a link in the infowindow to click on, which then would simply zoom to marker (as well as center on). No matter what I try to do it doesn't work here is my sample - thanks.

```
['loc1', 48.21, -102.18, 3, '<h3>Location 1</h3><p>some text<BR><BR>As of Date: 07/29/2013<BR><BR>more and more text<br><a onclick="map.setZoom((48.21, -102.18), 10)"><u>Zoom to Location 1</u></a>'],
```

Comment: `<a onclick href="...">` makes no sense. You probably mean it to be `<a onclick="...">`

Comment: @duncan I updated the code portion. When I click on it it zooms me out (the wrong direction and way to far) please help!???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

map.setZoom takes one parameter, an integer for zoom level.  You're passing it `(48.21, -102.18), 10`, which makes no sense.  You're probably trying to do both setCenter and setZoom at the same time, e.g. (no idea if this would work from the context of a link within an infowindow):

```
<a onclick="map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(48.21, -102.18)); map.setZoom(10); return false">
```

Comment: I need help with an 'actual' solution to adding this feature in the infowindow? While this may be correct, it doesn't help me much in fixing my problem...this site is so frustrating!!

Comment: It'll help if you add all your code handling the map to the question, not just a sample array of data

Comment: I don't think you understand, I need it to be this way for a reason. I would have approached this a different way then...